# Equality comparing objects

Tags: c#

I have code like this:

```
 public bool AreSame(CreditProposal creditProposal)
    {
        if (!ContractingParty.Equals(creditProposal.ContractingParty))
            return false;
        if (!UltimateParent.Equals(creditProposal.UltimateParent))
            return false;
        if (!Rebound.Equals(creditProposal.Rebound))
            return false;
        if (!ContactPerson.Equals(creditProposal.ContactPerson))
            return false;
        if (!DateOfVisit.Equals(creditProposal.DateOfVisit))
            return false;
      .... and so on 10 more times
```

Is there a way to do this more concise? Or will that mean I get into reflection hell?

Comment: Could you override the equality operator on CreditProposal?

Answer (score 4):

Override `Equals` method.

Check [this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182164%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

And notice `If you implement ==, you must implement !=`.

Comment: And if you override `Equals()`, [override GetHashCode() too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c/371348#371348)

Comment: @Marc point taken, it requires me some logic to understand your answer though ;)

Answer (score 2):

The instinctive way to handle this situation is to override the [`Object.Equals(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) method and implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) for your type.

However, overriding `Object.Equals` will prompt you to also override [`Object.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx), which is a lot harder to do correctly. Most notably, `GetHashCode()` must return the same value each time it is called on the same instance, and must return the same value for two objects which are considered equal. If your type is mutable, this becomes a real pain. (In fact, `GetHashCode()` is so difficult to implement correctly, there's a whole tag for it on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gethashcode)

The static implementation for `Equals` usually looks like this:

```
public static bool Equals(CreditProposal proposalA, CreditProposal proposalB)
{
    // Check whether both values are null.
    if(object.ReferenceEquals(proposalA, null) 
        && object.ReferenceEquals(proposalB, null))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether either value is null.
    if(object.ReferenceEquals(proposalA, null) 
        || object.ReferenceEquals(proposalB, null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether hashcodes are different.
    if(proposalA.GetHashCode() != proposalB.GetHashCode())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Check for value equality.
    return Party.Equals(
            proposalA.ContractingParty, 
            proposalB.ContractingParty)
        && ParentProposal.Equals(
            proposalA.UltimateParent, 
            proposalB.UltimateParent);
        // Add more conditions for equality here.
}
```

You would call this implementation from all your instance methods.